# Infinite sum of a product of convergent sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given a sequence $x_i >0 $ whose sum is absolutely convergent, i.e. $\sum_i x_i < \infty$  and another  convergent sequence $0 < y_i \rightarrow y^*$, is it true that 
$$\sum_i x_i y_i < \infty$$ ? Intuitively it seems correct, but I'm not sure how to prove this.

Thanks.

Comment: **Example:** $x_i=y_i=(-1)^i/\sqrt{i}$.

However, if $\sum_ix_i$ converges *absolutely* then $\sum_ix_iy_i$ does converge, even if $\{y_i\}$ is merely bounded.

Comment: Thanks for that example. The series in question is absolutely convergent and positive.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove it with the comparison test, and a lemma about series which says that if a series is  absolutely convergent, it is convergent.

Since $\sum y_i$ converges, $\lim_{i->\infty} y_i = 0$, so for $i$ sufficiently large we have $|y_i|<k$ for some positive real number $k$.

Note that John Dawkins's comment addresses this, he notes that it is sufficient for ${y_i}$ to be bounded.

Suppose sufficiently large means for $i>M$

$\sum_{i=M+1}^n |x_i||y_i| < k\sum_{i=M+1}^n |x_i|$ for all $n>M+1$ and since we know $\sum_i |x_i|$ exists, by the comparison test, $\sum_{i=M+1}^\infty |x_i||y_i|$ exists.

Then $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i||y_i|= \sum_{i=1}^{M} |x_i||y_i| + \sum_{i=M+1}^\infty |x_i||y_i|$ exists.

Since $\sum_{i=1}^\infty |x_i||y_i|$ exists, $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_iy_i$ exists,
as absolute convergence implies convergence.